# Get value of another column based on foreign key

Tags: php, mysql

I am displaying all data from a table in a view for the administrator in a web app.

The SQL looks something like this:

```
$organizations = $db->query("
    SELECT id, organization_name, owner_id
    FROM organizations
    ORDER BY created_on DESC
  ")->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

The part of the view I am working with is as follows:

```
<?php foreach($organizations as $organization): ?>
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo e($organization['organization_name']); ?></td>
     <td><?php echo e($organization['owner_id']); ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

This works exactly as expected but is not actually what I want to display as far as the `owner_id` (an int and the primary key of the `users` table)

This will generate a table with all the values as in the SQL statement and in particular it will render the `owner_id` to the view which is a foreign key related to my `users` table.

What I want to do is actually display the `name` of the owner that belongs to the `owner_id` instead of just showing the `id` (i.e... 32). How can I display the associated `name` of the user from the `users` table based on the foreign key `user_id` that is referenced?

Comment: Can you be more clear with expected results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a [`JOIN`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)) to link the two tables. The example below links the two tables on `owner_id` and includes the `user_name` in the result. You will need to use an alias in the SELECT in the case that any of the column names exist in both tables.

```sql
-- use alias and include user_name
SELECT o.id, o.organization_name, u.user_id, u.user_name 
-- alias the table as "o"
FROM organizations o 
-- alias the table as "u"
JOIN users u 
    -- link the tables here on owner_id
    ON o.owner_id = u.user_id 
ORDER BY o.created_on DESC
```

You can then output the value of the `user_name` column in your PHP like so:

```php
<td><?php echo e($organization['user_name']); ?></td>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [JOIN](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp).

```
$organizations = $db->query("
    SELECT organizations.id, organizations.organization_name, 
    users.user_name
    FROM organizations
    JOIN users ON organizations.owner_id = users.user_id
    ORDER BY organizations.created_on DESC
  ")->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Then in view, it can be used as

```
<?php foreach($organizations as $organization): ?>
   <tr>
     <td><?php echo e($organization['organization_name']); ?></td>
     <td><?php echo e($organization['user_name']); ?></td>
   </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```